# Maria MySQL upgraded from 10.1.x to 10.2.x but now has long semaphore waits

Tags: mysql

Upgraded Maria MySQL from 10.1 to 10.2, but we are now experiencing InnoDB: A long semaphore wait(s) that then result in the database crashing.
This happens when trying to restore a database, by running replace into tables command for a table containing 35M rows of data, at approx 20M - 32M rows, the system always crashes with semaphore waits (attempted this on multiple systems / VMS). This worked when using Maria 10.1 but doesn't since using 10.2, is there a magic setting needed? (other than setting innodb_adaptive_hash_index=0 that didn't work!) Also increased innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold from 600 to 1200, the Semaphore issue still remains.

**The system:**
Windows 10 Pro, 4GB RAM, Processor: 2GHz (x2) With an SSD (80+GB free)
Apache/2.4.33
10.2.14-MariaDB
PHP 7.2.3

**my.ini (extract - without directory paths)**
[mysqld]
port                           = 3306
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
character_set_client_handshake = FALSE
character_set_server           = utf8mb4
collation_server               = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
key_buffer_size                = 32M
myisam_recover_options         = FORCE,BACKUP
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
slave_max_allowed_packet       = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 100
lock_wait_timeout              = 1010
tmp_table_size                 = 32M
max_heap_table_size            = 32M
query_cache_type               = 1
query_cache_limit              = 32M
query_cache_min_res_unit       = 2k
query_cache_size               = 64M
query_cache_strip_comments     = 1
query_prealloc_size            = 8388608
max_connections                = 200
wait_timeout                   = 1000
interactive_timeout            = 1000
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 1200
table_definition_cache         = 400
table_open_cache               = 200
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_format             = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table          = ON
innodb_large_prefix            = 1
innodb_doublewrite             = 1
innodb_use_atomic_writes       = 0
innodb_use_fallocate           = 0
innodb_use_trim                = 0
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 64M
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 16M
innodb_purge_threads           = 2
innodb_defragment              = 1
innodb_use_mtflush             = 0
event_scheduler                = 1
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
long_query_time                = 20
min_examined_row_limit         = 100000
slow_query_log                 = 1
performance_schema             = on
innodb_adaptive_hash_index     = 0
innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold = 1200

***On looking at the error log produced:***

`2018-04-30 17:15:05 4032 [Note] InnoDB: A semaphore wait:`
`--Thread 20080 has waited at buf0buf.cc line 4151 for 893.00 seconds the semaphore:`
`S-lock on RW-latch at 00000205B1323C38 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1471`
`a writer (thread id 0) has reserved it in mode  exclusive`
`number of readers 0, waiters flag 1, lock_word: 0`
`Last time read locked in file row0ins.cc line 2901`
`Last time write locked in file buf0buf.cc line 5376`


`=====================================`
`2018-04-30 17:15:07 0x4774 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT`
`=====================================`
`Per second averages calculated from the last 45 seconds`
`-----------------`
`BACKGROUND THREAD`
`-----------------`
`srv_master_thread loops: 1274 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 2 srv_idle`
`srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1275`
`----------`
`SEMAPHORES`
`----------`
`OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 26785`
`--Thread 9020 has waited at ibuf0ibuf.cc line 2720 for 257.00 seconds the semaphore:`
`Mutex at 00007FF7A63838E0, Mutex IBUF created ibuf0ibuf.cc:516, lock var 2`

`------------`
`TRANSACTIONS`
`------------`
`Trx id counter 445872`
`Purge done for trx's n:o < 445826 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle`
`History list length 0`
`LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:`
`---TRANSACTION 283698441286496, not started`
`0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)`
`---TRANSACTION 445871, ACTIVE 258 sec inserting`
`mysql tables in use 1, locked 1`
`1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 16260`
`MySQL thread id 20, OS thread handle 19452, query id 6361 localhost ::1 peoplecounter update`
`REPLACE INTO`counter_activity`{... columns / values...}`
`--------`
`FILE I/O`
`--------`
`I/O thread 0 state: complete io for buf page (insert buffer thread)`
`I/O thread 1 state: complete io for buf page (log thread)`
`I/O thread 2 state: complete io for buf page (read thread)`
`I/O thread 3 state: complete io for buf page (read thread)`
`I/O thread 4 state: native aio handle (read thread)`
`I/O thread 5 state: native aio handle (read thread)`
`I/O thread 6 state: native aio handle (write thread)`
`I/O thread 7 state: native aio handle (write thread)`
`I/O thread 8 state: native aio handle (write thread)`
`I/O thread 9 state: native aio handle (write thread)`
`Pending normal aio reads: [1, 4, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:`
`Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0`
`6773 OS file reads, 2856999 OS file writes, 60709 OS fsyncs`
`0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed in the next MariaDB build, 10.2.15.
See https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15707?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true for details.